# How to setup and use webhook for new Instagram graph API

Tags: ssl, instagram, webhooks, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, callbackurl

My question is about how to setup and use Webhook for new Instagram graph API, I am integrating the new Instagram graph API with my application and I setup the SSL for my staging server and have created the callback function successfully, but when I insert callback URL for webhook it shows something like this ->

[webhook_callback_url_error_instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2iy8.png)

Please help me if someone has done it already...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to respond to the verification GET request as per the [Facebook Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started) page. See the Verification Requests section. The error message you shared is telling you the challenge has failed.